# Redux state reset when invocing new route using Vaadin router in Lit project

Tags: redux, vaadin, lit

I am using redux for state management and Vaadin router for SPA routing. If I invoke av new route by clicking a `<a href="/charger">Go to charger view</a>` the charger view renders in the router outlet and state remains intact. The problem arise when I want to invoke a new route changing the adress field or changing as `document.location.href = '/charger'`. In this case the redux store gets cleared. Does anyone know why and how to solv it?

Answer (score 1):

Manually changing the address field or setting `document.location.href` causes the browser to render the page from scratch. The only way to keep the state across those would be to persist the states in the redux store in a persistent storage like local storage or session storage.

There are libraries like [`redux-persist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) that help you do this or you could write your own.